# problems with DS3524 - no link

Tags: hard-drive, connection

Have DS3524 with SAS link and win server Some times ago link was down. Now I have no link to DS3524. But i can ping controller by IP and connect to it via telnet.

How can detect problem and Fix it?

Thanks!

P.S. one note - disks not started on switch on ds3524. Only when i release disk - green light blink shortly